# Assign Elastic IP to EC2 at startup via AWS CLI

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Im quite new to aws cli, I'm trying to run the command: `aws ec2 associate-address` when my ec2 start.

I'm using ubuntu 13 64 and I've created an sh file with that command and it works fine but not when I'm start the istance (or reboot).

I'm not very familiar with 'startup stuff', I tried rc.local init.d but it won't works

the point is how to fireup a sh script when the ec2 start basically

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear - are you trying to do this from within the instance, or from another system?

It sounds like you're trying to configure the instance to associate itself with an Elastic IP.  I've never actually tried to do this - instead, launch your instance into a VPC, give it a public IP address, and you don't have to worry about it.

If you want to run a script at startup, you can put an @reboot command into your crontab - I know the Amazon Linux AMI supports this, I'm not sure if the Ubuntu version does.

Comment: I'm trying to do it from the instance. Actually that's not the point I guess, I'm just trying to fire up an sh script everytime the ec2 start. the VPC can be a solution but it cost something to have it right?

Comment: I don't think there is any additional cost for running a VPC.  As of some time in the last couple of months, all new accounts run in a VPC by default.

Comment: Does it not get called, or is there an error in the script?  Remember that the cron env is NOT the same as running it as root - you will need to include the full path to most executables, for example.